# How can I split text into lines based on a regex expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I have snippets of text and I would like to divide these into lines. The problem is that they have been formatted and so I cannot split like I would normally do which is this way:

```
 _text = text.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .ToArray();
```

Here is the sample text:

```
 adj 1: around the middle of a scale of evaluation of physical
        measures; "an orange of average size"; "intermediate
        capacity"; "a plane with intermediate range"; "medium
        bombers" [syn: {average}, {intermediate}]
 2: (of meat) cooked until there is just a little pink meat
    inside
 n 1: a means or instrumentality for storing or communicating
      information
 2: the surrounding environment; "fish require an aqueous
    medium"
 3: an intervening substance through which signals can travel as
    a means for communication
 4: (bacteriology) a nutrient substance (solid or liquid) that
    is used to cultivate micro-organisms [syn: {culture medium}]
 5: an intervening substance through which something is
    achieved; "the dissolving medium is called a solvent"
 6: a liquid with which pigment is mixed by a painter
 7: (biology) a substance in which specimens are preserved or
    displayed
 8: a state that is intermediate between extremes; a middle
    position; "a happy medium"
```

The format is always the same:

- 1-3 letter word may be present
- number 1-10
- colon
- space
- text which may appear on multiple lines.

So in this case the line break would have to be something like the 1-3 char word followed by a 1-2 character number followed by a :

Can someone give me some advice on how I could do this with the split or with another method?

Update: Steven's answer but not quite sure how to fit that in my function. Here I show my original code and below that Steven's suggested answer but there is a part missing that I am not sure about:

```
    public parser(string text)
    {
        //_text = text.Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            // .ToArray();

        string pattern = @"(\w{1,3} )?1?\d: (?<line>[^\r\n]+)(\r?\n\s+(?<line>[^\r\n]+))*";
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text, pattern))
        {
            if (m.Success)
            {
                string entry = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                    m.Groups["line"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(x => x.Value));
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

For testing purposes here is the text in a different format:

"medium\n     adj 1: around the middle of a scale of evaluation of physical\n            measures; \"an orange of average size\"; \"intermediate\n            capacity\"; \"a plane with intermediate range\"; \"medium\n            bombers\" [syn: {average}, {intermediate}]\n     2: (of meat) cooked until there is just a little pink meat\n        inside\n     n 1: a means or instrumentality for storing or communicating\n          information\n     2: the surrounding environment; \"fish require an aqueous\n        medium\"\n     3: an intervening substance through which signals can travel as\n        a means for communication\n     4: (bacteriology) a nutrient substance (solid or liquid) that\n        is used to cultivate micro-organisms [syn: {culture medium}]\n     5: an intervening substance through which something is\n        achieved; \"the dissolving medium is called a solvent\"\n     6: a liquid with which pigment is mixed by a painter\n     7: (biology) a substance in which specimens are preserved or\n        displayed\n     8: a state that is intermediate between extremes; a middle\n        position; \"a happy medium\"\n     9: someone who serves as an intermediary between the living and\n        the dead; \"he consulted several mediums\" [syn: {spiritualist}]\n     10: transmissions that are disseminated widely to the public\n         [syn: {mass medium}]\n     11: an occupation for which you are especially well suited; \"in\n         law he found his true metier\" [syn: {metier}]\n     [also: {media} (pl)]\n"

Comment: doesnt feel like regex is yr best bet, do it the hard way

Comment: You have already defined the business rules. Second, not that much experience with regular expressions. For maintainability as well I would recommend to just write out the logic with a line-by-line parse to check for your conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex works nicely for this.  For instance:

```
public parser(string text)
{
    string pattern = @"(?<line> (\w{1,3} )?1?\d: [^\r\n]+)(\r?\n(?! (\w{1,3} )?1?\d: [^\r\n]+)\s+(?<line>[^\r\n]+))*";
    var entries = new List<string>();
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text, pattern))
        if(m.Success)
            entries.Add(string.Join(" ", 
                m.Groups["line"].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(x=>x.Value)));
    _text = entries.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: That looks very impressive.  Can you have a look at my question. I updated it to show where your code could be used but I am not sure what to do inside of the (m.Success) block.

Comment: Don't split it first.  The regex pattern needs the full multi-line input to work properly.

Comment: I wasn't splitting it.  Just left that part in so you could see where my original code was :-)

Comment: Ah.  Sorry.  Well, what is `_text`, a string array, presumably?  What is it supposed to be set to?  All of the lines, for the first entry, or all all entries, or what?  I'm confused by what output you are trying to get.

Comment: Can you confirm your regex will work even if there's no 1-3 character word at the start of each block and also if the number before the colon is 1 or 2 digits.  Thanks very much.

Comment: private string[] _text;   it's a local array with each element containing one line.  Hope that makes sense :-) It would probably have been cleaner if I had just returned _text from that function.

Comment: Yes.  It will work.  It only allows up to 10, though, since that's what you stipulated in your question.  Well, actually it only works up to 19.  Oops, I;ll fix that now.

Comment: When your fixing.  Can you add the function code around your answer so I can see where your answer fits as I'm confused by "// ...
" Thanks a lot

Comment: So the output should only contain the lines for the first entry or for all of them?  Should it include the first line (the one with the number) or only the ones that follow?

Comment: The output should be an array where each element represents a line starting with the xxx yy: ___  and the following lines right up until the next xxx yy: _____

Comment: So each item in the array should be multi-line, then, right?

Comment: Actually need to take the multi lines and put them all into one line.  Sorry if it's confusing.  It's data from a really bad XML API.

Comment: In this example element 1 of the array should contain: adj 1: around the middle of a scale of evaluation of physical
        measures; "an orange of average size"; "intermediate
        capacity"; "a plane with intermediate range"; "medium
        bombers" [syn: {average}, {intermediate}]

Comment: In this example element 2 of the array should contain: 2: (of meat) cooked until there is just a little pink meat
    inside

Comment: Should be a ten element array created from this not so easy to parse data.

Comment: I'm trying to get a chance to check it out. I will check out soon and update and accept your answer if all is okay. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Do you understand my code?  I wouldn't recommend using it if you don't understand it.  If you have any specific questions about it, I'd be happy to explain.  Regex is powerful, but you shouldn't use any technology that you don't understand.

Comment: I am trying to understand it.  When I ran your code it doesn't return anything and I made one change \r\n changed to just \n  but so far it still does not work. I added to the question the sample text. Sorry I should have added that earlier.  Notice there's the first line that should be skipped which is not being dealt with yet.  Looking at the sample text, can you see any reason why nothing would match with your regex? Thanks  btw almost 1am here so soon I have to sleep and will wake again in 8-9 hours.

Comment: The reason it wasn't working is because it had a space before the three letter word and number in the first line of each entry.  Based on your description of the format, I assumed that was not the case.  My pattern relied on that space not being there in order to determine where each entry ended.  Doing so with that space there is a bit more challenging, but still possible.  I've updated my answer to show one way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication106
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string inputLine = "";
            List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
            string pattern = @"(?'prefix'\w*)?\s*?(?'index'\d+):(?'text'.*)";
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            while ((inputLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                inputLine = inputLine.Trim();
                Match match = Regex.Match(inputLine, pattern);
                Data newData = new Data();
                data.Add(newData);
                newData.prefix = match.Groups["prefix"].Value;
                newData.index = int.Parse(match.Groups["index"].Value);
                newData.text = match.Groups["text"].Value;
            }
        }
    }
    public class Data
    {
        public string prefix { get; set; }
        public int index { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }
}
```